# Exit from function from inside Timeout

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

The problem is that I have a setTimeout function inside another one:

```
function checkBrowser() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(some.condition) //exit function checkBrowser() here
  },5000);
  setTimeout(/*something that mustn't run if some.condition is true*/,5000);

}
```

I need to exit the first function from inside setTimeout. Help.

Comment: Why? The code in `setTimeout` will never be called until the code in `checkBrowser` is completed.

Comment: call checkbrowser before setting the timeout?

Comment: I've updated the question. I have 2 or more setTimeouts. And if some.condition is true, the next setTimeouts mustn't run.

Comment: register the 2nd timeout in the first timeout when the conditions are met. It's the only way to do it

Comment: Please explain the original idea of `checkBrowser()`. Why are you need timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The code is asynchronous.

The first function will have finished running and exited before the function you pass to `setTimeout` has even been called.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for helping! I've done it in another way:

```
function checkBrowser() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(some.condition) {
      //something here
    } else {
      setTimeout(/*something that mustn't run if some.condition is true*/,5000);
    }
  },5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running your conditionals in the asynchronous / retarded timeline and once you enter into that timeline there is no way out. You must remain there all the way your logic goes including any recursive activity. However i would advise you to use promises and move all logic to the `then` part for sake of functional programming.

Let's first take our functions one by one and see how all gets geared up by the promises.

OK lets assume that we have a generic async function called `waitAndDoStg` which takes a data and a callback as two of it's arguments. Let's assume our callback is of error first type.

```
var waitAndDoStg = (data,cb) => setTimeout(_=> cb(false, data.value),data.duration),
```

It will never return any errors. So after `data.duration` milliseconds pass it will invoke our callback like `cb(false, data.value)` and will pass the data it took from us back to us. A stupid function is what it is.

So ok we need to promisfy this async function. We have a standard promisfy utility function which takes any async function provided and gives us a promise out from it. The callback has to be error first type though.

```
promisfy = (data,func) => new Promise((v,x) => func(data,(err,res) => err ? x(err) : v(res)));
```

OK, instead of `resolve` and `reject` i use `v` and `x` names respectively. Well i guess it is reasonable to use `v` for `resolve` since it looks like a check mark and `x` is fine for `reject` i suppose.

So here is the rest of the code. It's promises and recursive and everything but i guess functionally this is a very readable code.

```js
var     promisfy = (data,func) => new Promise((v,x) => func(data,(err,res) => err ? x(err) : v(res)));
  decrementByOne = n => --n,
    waitAndDoStg = (data,cb) => setTimeout(_=> cb(false, data.value),data.duration),
countDownPromise = n => {n && console.log(n);
                         promisfy({value:n, duration:1000}, waitAndDoStg)
                         .then(decrementByOne)
                         .then(val => val !== 0 ? countDownPromise(val)
                                                : console.log("Ignition...!"));
                        };
countDownPromise(3);
```